# child process(es) died unexpectedly, aborting while loading into cassandra using COPY command

Tags: cassandra

I have deployed cassandra cluster in  kubernetes environment as pods.
I have 2 cassandra pods/nodes and each with  have 12 GB RAM, 1 VCPU and using distributed storage for data.
When I tried to load data using COPY command it saying "child process(es) died unexpectedly, aborting ".

```
cqlsh> COPY aarun.emp FROM '/home/etolaru/cass-data/testfile' WITH DELIMITER='|' AND HEADER = TRUE;
Using 16 child processes
Starting copy of aarun.emp with columns [rownumber, cell, counternames, countervals, datetime, group]                                                                                                          .
Failed to import 0 rows: NoHostAvailable - ,  given up after 1 attempts
Failed to import 0 rows: NoHostAvailable - ,  given up after 1 attempts
4 child process(es) died unexpectedly, aborting
Processed: 5000 rows; Rate:     593 rows/s; Avg. rate:     489 rows/s
5000 rows imported from 0 files in 10.227 seconds (0 skipped).
```

I have seen debug logs also but I don't see any info about why this child proess died. have enough resources, and the file I am loading is 109MB file.

```
cqlsh> COPY aarun.emp FROM '/home/etolaru/cass-data/testfile' WITH DELIMITER='|' AND HEADER = TRUE --debug;
Using 16 child processes
Starting copy of aarun.emp with columns [rownumber, cell, counternames, countervals, datetime, group]                                                                                                          .
Failed to import 0 rows: NoHostAvailable - ,  given up after 1 attempts
Failed to import 0 rows: NoHostAvailable - ,  given up after 1 attempts
4 child process(es) died unexpectedly, aborting
Processed: 5000 rows; Rate:     593 rows/s; Avg. rate:     489 rows/s
5000 rows imported from 0 files in 10.227 seconds (0 skipped).
```

I expect all records in file should load into cassandra DB with out any issue.
Please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Comment: No info in either node's logs? Are all filesystems in tact (i.e. nothing 100%)?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your file has proper encodings and there are no special characters in them (Ensure UTF-8, Haven't tested ASCII), To test it out, try loading the same file on a PostgreSQL Server since copy command shares a lot of similarity with PostgreSQL data dumps. This will help ensuring your input data has no issues, Also I read somewhere that "COPY FROM" should be limited to smaller files like 1-2 GB(Max) and not more.